# Could not install packages due to Environment error: [Errno 22]

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip

In my MacOS I was trying to install jupyter via running below command

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
```

but at the end it says

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 
'/Users/gotcha/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/-andocfilters-1.4.2.dist-info/.'
```

I do not understand what to do now?

Comment: Did you intend to use Python 2? Also, are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: I am using python 2.7 only and I am not using virtual environments.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for either of those?

Comment: No particular reason.

Comment: Then I would recommend Python 3 and virtual environments (or similar)!